# If a player run behind a wall, use Hide, then comes out, they will still be "hidden"?

Tags: dnd-5e, stealth

**If a player run behind a wall, use Hide (as an action), then comes out, they will still be "hidden"?**

I'm the DM at this table ***(Lost Mine of Phandelver, 5e)***, and our *Halfling Rogue*, is doing that to gain the advantage attack from [Unseen Attackers](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/5e_SRD:Unseen_Attackers_and_Targets).

His actions goes like following:

1. Run behind a wall (in the corner or behind the stairs for example).
2. Use [Rogue's Cunning Action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#CunningAction-345) to Hide as a bonus action.
3. On his next turn, move 5 feet (just to get out of the wall) and attack (with a bow) the enemy with advantage from [Unseen Attackers](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/5e_SRD:Unseen_Attackers_and_Targets).
4. repeat.

When he uses the hide action, I ask him for a **Stealth** check, then I compare with the enemies **Passive Perception**.

Because he is a Rogue with +7 stealth, is very hard to actually detect him.

Are we using Hide correctly? Should I keep letting he have the Unseen Attackers advantage?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Please review the linked question and check whether it matches yours; if not, please edit your question to clarify what's not already addressed there. Hope you stick around? :)